# Scope in the modal window (AngularJS directive)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am trying to use a modal window (see http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

In the parent controller I have the following function:

```
    $scope.open = function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',            
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
            year: function () {
                return $scope.year.value;
            },
            month: function () {
                return $scope.month;
            },
            day: function () {
                return $scope.day.name;
            },
            todos: function () {
                return $scope.day.toDoItems;
            }
        },
        backdrop: 'static'
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (todos) {
        angular.forEach(todos, function (todo) {
            if (todo.New)
                $scope.day.toDoItems.push(todo);
        });            
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};
```

And in the modal controller there is an addTodo function:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, year, month, day, todos) {
...
    $scope.todos = todos; 
    $scope.addTodo = function () {
        $scope.todos.push({ TodoText: $scope.todoText.value, Done: false, Del: false, Date: new Date(year, month, day), Priority: 1, New: true});
        $scope.todoText.value = "";
    };
...
$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.todos);
    };
};
```

In the parent view there is shown a calendar with `todos` per day. When clicking on a day's header the modal window is open and you can add todos. My problem is that when adding todos in modal window, also the `todos` are added to parent view, at the same moment. 
Now the `todos` are added twice in the parent view: once at the moment they are added in modal view and once I click OK on modal view.
But I want the `todos` items to be added to parent view only when clicking OK on modal view.

Have anyone a solution for this? Thanks in advance!

You can see in Plunker how it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nr1h7K3WZyWlRlrwzhM3?p=info

Comment: Can you illustrate that in Fiddle?

Comment: I have been added a link from Plunker, I can't edit in Fiddle the html tag (and I have to specify the ng-app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your resolve object for the modal controller you're actually passing the parent's scope todos object back as a reference so when you assign it in your modal's controller `$scope.todos = todos;` its actually pointing to the parent's `todos` scope variable.  You can return a copy of the parent's todos instead of a reference to the variable.

```
todos: function () {
    return angular.copy($scope.day.toDoItems);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ty10C8JOKHlwb2bWA89r?p=info